# C# add item in abstract list

Tags: c#, class, abstract

For a project i am working with intherentance and an abstract class. with the help of a form i want to add items into a list, but get the following error during coding: cannot create an instance abstract type or interface 'Article'. does someone know how to fixt his?

articlemanager class:

```
 private List<Article> items;

        public ArticleManager()
        {
            items = new List<Article>();
        }
        public void addArticleEmergency(Article emergencyNews)
        {
            items.Add(emergencyNews);
        }
```

abstract article class:

```
  abstract class Article
    {
        public int id { get; private set; }
        public string title { get; private set; }
        public string text { get; private set; }

        public Article(int id, string title, string text)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public bool HasID(int id)
        {
            if (id == this.id)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return id + ": \r\n" + title + " \r\n " + text;
        }
    }
}
```

form:

```
private ArticleManager articalManagerAdd;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.articalManagerAdd = new ArticleManager();
        }

      
        private void btnMakeNewsArticle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtNewsNumber.Text == "" || txtNewsTitle.Text == "" || txtNewsText.Text == "" || !rbEmergency.Checked && !rbNormal.Checked )
            {
                lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Clear();
                lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Add("Please fill in all the required information");
            }
            else
            {
                if (articalManagerAdd.GetArticle(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewsNumber.Text)) == null)
                {
                    if (rbNormal.Checked)
                    {
                        articalManagerAdd.addArticleNormal(new Article(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewsNumber.Text), txtNewsTitle.Text, txtNewsText.Text));
                        MessageBox.Show("Normal news article has been added");
                    }
                    else if(rbEmergency.Checked)
                    {
                        Article emergencyNews = new NewsArticle(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewsNumber.Text), txtNewsTitle.Text, txtNewsText.Text);
                        MessageBox.Show("Emergency news article has been added");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Add("This id has already been used");
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an abstract class. This is what `abstract` means. Either derive a concrete class from it or remove the "abstract"

Comment: to add to the comment from klaus , think of an abstract class as a blueprint for other classes. so you define how a class should look like but you dont do a concrete implementation of the methods. That you do in the dereived classes

Comment: Why did you make your class abstract? This is not meant as scolding, but as a serious question. You apparently have some misconception about what "abstract" means, and the key to solving this issue is to fix that misconception.

Comment: My teacher said to use abstract. I din't know that you couldn't use it.

Comment: Isn't your teacher expected to actually _teach_? Maybe have a look into : [Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: _"I din't know that you couldn't use it."_ you can _use_ it. You just cannot create an instance of it. That's the point. You can derive sub-classes from it. Then the child has an "is-a" relation to its parent. That means you could do for example `Parent p = new Child();` or in a method `void doSomething(Parent p){}` you could pass any descendant of the Parent class ( anything that is-a Parent ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an error instantiating an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611412/why-do-i-get-an-error-instantiating-an-interface)

Comment: i just don't understand how that works with a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

So your code `new Article(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewsNumber.Text), txtNewsTitle.Text, txtNewsText.Text))` will not compile.

You can inherit from a non-abstract class so your `NewsArticle` class would be expected to work if you just removed the `abstract`  modifier to your `Article` class.

Alternatively you could add a new sub-class of `Article` say `NormalArticle` and use that in your `addArticleNormal` method

Comment: how do you make a sub-class? i am not that familiar yet with c#

Comment: In the same way (I assume) that `NewsArticle` is. `public class NormalArticle : Article`